# Python (TypeError: 'float' object is not callable)

Tags: python

I keep getting this message (TypeError: 'float' object is not callable) from line 38 (np.log(m0-me*t)/me) does anyone know why? Would appreciate some help since I am new to python, thank you.

```
import math
import numpy as np

"""
    Input
""" 

ISP    = 130    #[s]
t_burn = 3.0    #[s]
g0     = 9.81   #[m/s^2]
mf     = 12.0   #[Kg]
D_R    = 0.12   #[m]
C_D    = 0.4
rho    = 1.225
A      = math.pi*D_R**2/4
Apogeu = 0.0
me     = 0.1
v      = []
h      = []

while (Apogeu<3000):
    
    m0   = mf + me
    t    = 0.0
    while (t<=20):
        
        if t==0.0:
            v = 0.0
            
        elif t<=t_burn:
            v = ISP*g0*np.log(m0/(m0-me*t))-g0*t-C_D*0.5*A*v(t-0.01)**2*\
            np.log(m0-me*t)/me
            h = ISP*g0/me*((m0-me*t)*np.log((m0-me*t)/m0)+me*t)-g0*0.5*t**2\
            -C_D*0.5*A*v(t-0.01)**2/me*((t-m0/me)*np.log(m0-me*t)+m0/me-t)
            
        elif t>t_burn:
            v = v(t_burn)-g0*t-C_D*0.5*A*v(t-0.01)**2/mf*t
            h = h(t_burn) + v(t_burn)*t -0.5*g0*t**2-\
            C_D*0.5*A*v(t-0.01)**2*t**2*0.5/mf
            if h > Apogeu:
                Apogeu = h

        print("Apogeu=",Apogeu,"m")
    t = t + 0.1
    me = me + 0.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if t==0.0:
            v = 0.0
```

Then

```
v = ISP*g0*np.log(m0/(m0-me*t))-g0*t-C_D*0.5*A*v(t-0.01)**2*\
            np.log(m0-me*t)/me
```

Specifically `v(t-0.01)`. It's calling v. In fact, you made this mistake in several parts. Are you coming from Matlab perhaps?  If you want to access some element in a list, use square brackets.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is this line:

```
v(t-0.01)
```

It should be:

```
v*(t-0.01)
```

Because `v` is not a function.

Comment: As well as `v(t_burn)` and `h(t_burn)`

Answer (score 1):

This is because the variable `v` is set to the float `0.0` in a previous loop.

```py
if t == 0.0:
    # v is set to the float 0.0 in one iteration of the loop.
    v = 0.0

elif t <= t_burn:
    # Then `v` is called as a function here, but it's still the float 0.0
    #                                              
    v = ISP*g0*np.log(m0/(m0-me*t))-g0*t-C_D*0.5*A*v(t-0.01)**2*\
            np.log(m0-me*t)/me
```

It may help catch errors like this if your variables were a bit more verbose and you add more whitespace to your code.